# Continuous Delivery : Maintaining Feature flags and Newer Implementations behind feature toggles

Tags: java, object-oriented

### Problem Statement

I have a class named Mapper and with a method `mapTo` which goes through a map of rows and checks types of key and do a casting and store it in a new map.

```
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Mapper {

    public static Map<String, Object> mapTo(Map<String, Object> row, Map<String, String> columnTypes) {

        Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();

        for(String key: row.keySet()) {
            String dataType = columnTypes.get(key);

            Object value = row.get(key);

            if(value!=null) {
                if (dataType.equals("timestamp")) {
                    Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) value;
                    row.put(key, new DateTime(timestamp.getTime()));
                } else if (dataType.equals("bool")) {
                    Boolean bool = (Boolean) row.get(key);
                    row.put(key, bool);
                } else if (dataType.equals("integer")) {
                    Integer intValue = (Integer) row.get(key);
                    row.put(key, intValue);
                } else {
                    row.put(key, value.toString());
                }
            }

        }

        return row;
    }

}
```

Now the implementation that is using this method has been changed and now requires a small change in Mapper implementation.

### Change :

when dataType equals timestamp then do a cast with long instead of DateTime.

```
if (dataType.equals("timestamp")) {
                    Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) value;
                    bigQueryRow.put(key, timestamp.getTime());
                }
```

### Possible Options

- Change the implementation directly in Mapper class and let the new implementation use it but

  - Bad : It will break the existing implementation in case I want to use that
    as well.
  - Good : No code duplication
- Add a new Implementation i.e. `MapperV1` and introduce this small change and keep everything else same.

  - Good : This new implementation will be behind feature toggle so easily can switch to old implementation if I want
  - Bad : Lots of code duplication in new MapperV1.

Each of above approaches has their merits and demerits.

I am facing this problem as a general problem when it comes to managing new implementation behind feature toggles when new implementation has small diff from previous implementation.

### Questions

I would like to learn from this amazing community.

- What are best practices to manage feature toggles and related implementations in scenarios like these.
- Can we avoid lots of duplication of code without breaking the previous implementation ?
- I thought of refactoring this method to pass predicates and functions but is it a good idea ?
- Lastly if there is any feedback on the code itself ?

Comment: You are introducing a local variable with the same name as the method parameter, which will not compile and would render the question as off topic. Also there is a lot to be desired regarding structure and naming. Is this "anonymized" code from work? I would rather review the actual code instead of wadsting time pointing out stuff in the parts you changed just to hide proprietary details.

Comment: Asking about code that you haven't written yet is specifically [outside the scope](/help/on-topic) of Code Review.  If you implement your suggested options, then you could request a [tag:comparative-review] of them.  That's probably your best option if you actually want review.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen Thanks for pointing that out. Yes I have changed the names of the variables and methods only. Now regarding your point of `I would rather review the actual code instead of wadsting time pointing out stuff in the parts you changed just to hide proprietary details.` How would then someone ask for code review where it is not possible to share exact code for some reasons ?

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the comment. I have written that code specifically which was shared. I had implemented those possible options as well. It didn't look right to me to share the code of those options because anyone can easily understand how would I have coded them. So I tried to keep the question simple without introducing any unnecessary code which reader can understand easily with the text provided :).

Comment: @SRJ If your employer prevents you from asking for an outside review, then posting one puts you into legal jeopardy, so I would not even attempt to circumvent it. I would ask for a code review from collagues within the company. Corporate world sucks oftentimes.

Answer (score 2):

## no null guard

```
            String dataType = columnTypes.get(key);
```

Apparently you're confident the `.get` will never return null.
Ok, fair enough.
I'm not familiar with this use case's context, so I'll have to believe you.

```
                if (dataType.equals("timestamp")) {
```

In cases where it *could* be null, standard idiom would be:

```
                if ("timestamp".equals(dataType)) {
```

---

## switch

Consider using `switch(dataType)`
instead of repeatedly testing it with `if`.

---

## command pattern

Consider storing four command helpers in a Map:
{time, bool, int, default string}.
You can dispatch to appropriate helper with a single `.get`,
with the string case appropriately defaulted.

This lets you replace a single isolated helper based on feature flag.
In other words, your function which does four things was doing
[too much](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

You can dispatch on type, or dispatch on (type, version).

---

## dispatch through overloads

It appears that `dataType` is redundant with what java already
knows about the type of `Object value`.
There are four different calls to `row.put(key, ...)`
which dispatch to different code based on `value`'s type.

Consider writing four overloaded helpers which accept four different types.

---

## versioning

Different versions store different time data.

- v1: `DateTime`
- v2: `long` milliseconds since epoch

The OP didn't mention having distinct tables for v1 & v2 data.

I'm a little concerned that interleaving v1 & v2 rows into
same table will produce maintenance headaches as you
roll the version forward and backward.
Consider adding a version column to the table.

Imagine a reporting component that knows how to
tack on a WHERE clause so we retrieve "last 7 days" worth of rows.
It might plausibly tack on `AND version <= 1`
before submitting the query, reflecting the fact
that it knows about the table's organization
up through the component's own release date.
A more modern report would know how to cope with both data variants.

This sort of thing can be quite conveniently handled through VIEWs.

```
CREATE VIEW SALES_V1  AS SELECT *  FROM SALES  WHERE version <= 1;
CREATE VIEW SALES_V2  AS SELECT *  FROM SALES  WHERE version <= 2;
```

Then point the reporting component at the appropriate view.

Sometimes a feature flag *adds* a new column,
which is pretty harmless for old code,
at least if you habitually name query columns
in preference to writing `SELECT *`.
When a feature flag *deletes* a column (including renames)
or *modifies* the semantics of a column,
it becomes pretty hard for old code to respond gracefully.
Best practice for such cases is usually to invent
a new table name.
Either migrate old rows into the new table,
or use a VIEW that combines them with UNION ALL
plus appropriate transforms,
such as date rewrites for the OP use case.

Comment: Some nice ideas. Thanks. Regarding question of versioning, there is no database involved and it is a helper method so end results are same. It is just intermediate layer which used to accept `DateTime` now changed and accepts `long` but it doesn't affect end result. Now my question is still how do I manage the new implementation behind feature flag and avoid any duplicate code ? Did I miss if you've already answered this question ?

Comment: You're dispatching to four different (very small!) pieces of code. So you probably need four helpers. Then add a fifth for the v2 "long instead of DateTime" behavior. Dispatch as you wish, via `if` or `switch` or overload or indirect through a method object retrieved from `Map`. Me? I'd prolly go with that last one. // Say you have 4 helpers. Rather than adding a 5th, you might put some `if v1 else v2` logic within the time helper. It's hard to predict how your future versions will go -- some upgrade paths will be painful with `if`, `if`, `if` tests.